# How do I 'find' a string from a file and display it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file with data stored in it (string data, such as names, addresses ,etc.) and I want to know how i can using a search function like:

```
search = input("Enter keyword(s) here:")
```

to search a file  , ex 'File1.txt' and display any words that have the key characters or word in it and how I can make it display that specific word.

lets assume that these are the string data in 'File1.txt' (if it helps):

> Smith,
>
> Jones,
>
> Karla,
>
> Lee,
>
> Sherry.